# How to delete entire cosmosdb partition using spirngboot

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

What's the easiest way to delete an entire partition in cosmos Db assuming that I'm using spirngboot with SQL API?

I have a class marked with the `@Repository` that extends the `CosmosRepository` and I want to delete every item from a particular partition.

I know that with `CosmosClientBuilder` I could do something like:

```kotlin
cosmosDbClient.getDatabase(dataBaseName)
              .getContainer(container)
              .deleteAllItemsByPartitionKey(
                   PartitionKey("partitionKey0001"), 
                   CosmosItemRequestOptions())
```

Is it possible to access the container from the repository?

I don't want to use stored procedures for something that should be easy to do.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is releasing this feature since year now.

Its yet in preview state and you will need to opt to this before using

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).